# Deploy Java webapp on AWS EC2 from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-ec2, eclipse-plugin

I am getting started with AWS plugin for Eclipse (Juno)
I've seen that it is possible to deploy some app on Amazon Elastic BeanStalk, which is great, but I'd prefer to deploy it directly to a specific EC2 instance (mostly for cost optimisation)

Has anyone done that before, or will I have to write my own Eclipse plugin to do so ?

According to :
http://blog.rajithdelantha.com/2011/10/complete-guide-to-deploy-java-web.html , creating an EC2 server (to be used like a Tomcat) is possible, but I can't find the option, I just have Tomcat6/7 for EBS.

Comment: My advice - don't use Eclipse for deployment. Don't use Eclipse at all it is very slow and it is always causing troubles.

Comment: Well, I agree that using Eclipse for deployment is not the best idea. But it will be a real time saver for me. Besides, I think Eclipse is great for development, and I don't see any reason to stop using it.

Comment: It is wacky turtle - it can't save you time. Use Alt + Tab to switch to the terminal to run your deployment targets! I use Sublime Text 2 and it is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

With an EC2 server you can run whatever web server you want, it's basically just a VM.  You could run Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, etc.  Almost all of those web servers have plugins or tools to enable deployment from Eclipse which are completely independent of Amazon.  For example, if you choose to setup Tomcat on your EC2 server then you could follow [these](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/index.html) (there may be newer) instructions.

Comment: Not relevant. The problem is not to deploy a Tomcat on EC2, it is to do deploy a project on a Tomcat running on a specific EC2 instance.

Comment: The instructions I linked to show how to deploy a project on Tomcat.  It doesn't matter in the slightest what Tomcat is running on.